# how do i filter queries by records in other tables? - laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

here is my current issue im trying to figure out

i have a laravel query for example below

```
$users = User::where('country', $country)

            ->where('age', '>=' , $lfmin)
            ->where('age', '<=' , $lfmax)
            ->get();                


            return $users;
```

and this works out all well and good. but I now have another sql table called datingblockedusers. each record in that table has the user id of the blockee and blocker. I also created a static function in datingblockeduser model that goes like this

```
public static function checkblock($id1, $id2)
{
    //check user is blocked
    $query = Datingblockeduser::where('uone', $id1)->where('utwo', $id2)->get();
    if($query->count() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $query = Datingblockeduser::where('utwo', $id1)->where('uone', $id2)->get();
        if($query->count() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How do i filter my main query such that the id of each user in that query is not in the datingblockeduser table under the fields uone or utwo (user one or user two)

EDIT: I wanted to implement a block list kind of related to a friends list. I created a new migration as such

```
Schema::create('blocked_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('blocked_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('blocked_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

and in the user model i did this

```
// blocked
public function blocked()
{
    $blocked = $this->belongsToMany('User', 'blocked_user', 'user_id', 'blocked_id');
    return $blocked;
}
public function block_user($blocked_id)
{
    $this->blocked()->attach($blocked_id);   // add friend
    $blocked = User::find($blocked_id);       // find your friend, and...
    $blocked->blocked()->attach($this->id);  // add yourself, too
}
public function remove_blocked($blocked_id)
{
    $this->blocked()->detach($blocked_id);   // remove friend
    $blocked = User::find($blocked_id);       // find your friend, and...
    $blocked->blocked()->detach($this->id);  // remove yourself, too
}
```

now can i now use it as part of the query above or any other query from now on to make sure i only return users who are not on the blocked list?

Comment: you need to create relationship between those two tables;

Comment: a many to many relationship? because as far as i can see its a many to many relationship between two user ids but in the same user table. is there a way to use the datingblockedusers table as a pivot table for relationships in the same table?

Comment: one to one I guess user can be blocked or not ?

Comment: i decided on many to many because blocked list should be like friends list. same type of relation. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you query all blocked user_id than change main query using `whereNotIn()`

```
// get blocked user id by authenticated user. (change where condition yourself)
$blockedId = Datingblockeduser::where('blocker_id', auth()->id())->pluck('id');

$users = User::where('country', $country)
            ->whereNotIn('id', $blockedId)
            ->where('age', '>=' , $lfmin)
            ->where('age', '<=' , $lfmax)
            ->get();
```